# Why changing bg color for button changes its border and how to avoid this

Tags: html, css, button, background-color

Here is an example of changing bg-color for HTML `button` element.

[image]

```html
<button style="">No</button>
<button style="background-color: #008CBA;">Blue</button>
<button style="background-color: #f44336;">Red</button>
```

Why changing just bg-color changes its border and how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

While there isn't any evidence behind this specific behaviour. But I believe the core reason for the observed behaviour is that each browser applies its own default styling to HTML elements, especially form elements like `<input>` and `<button>`. This default styling is what gives each browser its unique look and feel for basic HTML elements.

When you attempt to alter these styles *(In most scenarios, the styles related to `border` and `background`)*, browsers may revert to their unstyled or default appearance. This is because not all style properties are uniformly supported across different browsers, leading to inconsistencies. It's important to note that while there are differences, they are generally close in appearance.

Here's a simple example demonstrating how a browser might apply default styling to an `input` element:

```html
<input type="text">
<input style="border-width: 2px;" type="text" />
<input style="background-color: red;" type="text" />
```

And there are some other variations for the `button` element that leads to this behaviour:

```html
<button style="">Button</button>
<button style="background-color: #f44336;">Red</button>
<button style="border-width: 2px;">border width</button>
<button style="border-image: none;">border image</button>
<button style="border-radius: 2px;">border radius</button>
```